# Perl regex start match search after (skip) N char

Tags: regex, perl, offset, skip

Probably basic question, but can't find the answer:
I have a pattern match regex where I'm looking for 'G', 187 char and 'G' again, in a large buffer. This works well with `$s =~ m/(G.{187}G)/s`. Sometimes I want to add an offset of `N` bytes to the search (I don't want to start at position 0 of the buffer). I now I can do `$s =~ m/.{N}(G.{187}G)/s` but this sounds to me like not very efficient as I don't want to parse at all the beginning buffer (and it might be big). I tried to work with `\G` but could not get it to right.

Thanks

Comment: Just FYI: `\G` matches the start of string or the end of the preceding successful match, I doubt it can help.

Comment: I was trying to use pos() that I thought would "artificially" set the end of the preceding search but I got that wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the speed of the two approaches:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

use Benchmark qw(:all);
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

GetOptions( "case=i" => \my $case ) or die("Error in command line arguments\n");

my $num_cases = 5;
sub case1 { return (187, 2000) };
sub case2 { return (5, 10000) };
sub case3 { return (5, 20000) };
sub case4 { return (10000, 20000) };
sub case5 { return (5, 40000) };

my @cases = ( $case );
if ( !defined $case ) {
    @cases = 1..$num_cases;
}
for my $case ( @cases ) {
    run_case( $case );
}

sub run_case {
    my ( $case ) = @_;

    my $case_coderef = \&{"case" . $case};
    my ( $M, $N ) = $case_coderef->();
    say "Running case $case: \$M = $M, \$N = $N";

    my $prefix = 'A' x $N;
    my $middle = 'B' x $M;
    my $match_str = 'G' . $middle . 'G';

    my $str = $prefix . $match_str;

    my %methods = map {; "method$_" => \&{"method" . $_} } 1..6;

    for my $meth (keys %methods) {
        my $res = eval {
            $methods{$meth}->($str, $M, $N)
        };
        if ( $@ ) {
            print "$@";
            say "Skipping method '$meth'..";
            delete $methods{$meth};
            next;
        }   
        die "Method '$meth' failed.\n" if $res ne $match_str;
    }

    my %code = map { $_ => eval ('sub { $methods{' . $_ . '}->($str, $M, $N) }') } sort keys %methods; 

    cmpthese(-5, \%code );
}

sub method1 {
    my ( $str, $M, $N ) = @_;
    $str =~ m/.{$N}(G.{$M}G)/;
    return $1;
}

sub method2 {
    my ( $str, $M, $N ) = @_;
    pos( $str ) = $N;
    $str =~ m/\G(G.{$M}G)/;
    return $1;
}

sub method3 {
    my ( $str, $M, $N ) = @_;
    pos( $str ) = $N;
    $str =~ m/(G.{$M}G)/g;
    return $1;
}

sub method4 {
    my ( $str, $M, $N ) = @_;
    $str =~ m/.{$N}(G.{$M}G)/s;
    return $1;
}

sub method5 {
    my ( $str, $M, $N ) = @_;
    pos( $str ) = $N;
    $str =~ m/\G(G.{$M}G)/s;
    return $1;
}

sub method6 {
    my ( $str, $M, $N ) = @_;
    pos( $str ) = $N;
    $str =~ m/(G.{$M}G)/gs;
    return $1;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Running case 1: $M = 187, $N = 2000
             Rate method1 method3 method2 method6 method5 method4
method1  696485/s      --    -37%    -39%    -44%    -46%    -57%
method3 1112322/s     60%      --     -3%    -10%    -13%    -32%
method2 1146132/s     65%      3%      --     -7%    -10%    -30%
method6 1234678/s     77%     11%      8%      --     -3%    -24%
method5 1278898/s     84%     15%     12%      4%      --    -21%
method4 1629148/s    134%     46%     42%     32%     27%      --
Running case 2: $M = 5, $N = 10000
             Rate method1 method2 method6 method5 method3 method4
method1  226784/s      --    -72%    -72%    -72%    -72%    -78%
method2  801020/s    253%      --     -0%     -2%     -3%    -23%
method6  802386/s    254%      0%      --     -1%     -3%    -23%
method5  814132/s    259%      2%      1%      --     -1%    -22%
method3  823653/s    263%      3%      3%      1%      --    -21%
method4 1046605/s    361%     31%     30%     29%     27%      --
Running case 3: $M = 5, $N = 20000
             Rate method1 method3 method2 method6 method5 method4
method1  122763/s      --    -90%    -90%    -90%    -90%    -92%
method3 1252858/s    921%      --     -0%     -1%     -2%    -23%
method2 1258330/s    925%      0%      --     -1%     -1%    -22%
method6 1265165/s    931%      1%      1%      --     -1%    -22%
method5 1274309/s    938%      2%      1%      1%      --    -21%
method4 1622943/s   1222%     30%     29%     28%     27%      --
Running case 4: $M = 10000, $N = 20000
             Rate method1 method3 method2 method6 method5 method4
method1   90687/s      --    -62%    -62%    -93%    -93%    -94%
method3  236835/s    161%      --     -1%    -81%    -81%    -86%
method2  238334/s    163%      1%      --    -81%    -81%    -85%
method6 1236025/s   1263%    422%    419%      --     -3%    -25%
method5 1270943/s   1301%    437%    433%      3%      --    -22%
method4 1638548/s   1707%    592%    588%     33%     29%      --
Running case 5: $M = 5, $N = 40000
Quantifier in {,} bigger than 32766 in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/.{ <-- HERE 40000}(G.{5}G)/ at ./p.pl line 83.
Skipping method 'method4'..
Quantifier in {,} bigger than 32766 in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/.{ <-- HERE 40000}(G.{5}G)/ at ./p.pl line 63.
Skipping method 'method1'..
             Rate method2 method3 method6 method5
method2 1253528/s      --     -1%     -1%     -2%
method3 1260746/s      1%      --     -0%     -1%
method6 1263378/s      1%      0%      --     -1%
method5 1278718/s      2%      1%      1%      --
```

I ran this on my Laptop using Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz running Ubuntu 16.10, the result shows that using the `s` modifier can speed up `method1` dramatically ( compare with `method4`). But `method1` or `method4` cannot be used when `$N` exceeds 32766.

Comment: Thanks - That answers the question. I still don't know why I was not able to have  $str =~ m/\G(G.{$M}G)/s; to work ... but anyway, as the method1 is faster, this is perfect

Answer (score 2):

*Benchmarked: as more than a few hundred chars is skipped `pos` gets much faster than `.{N}`*

---

You can set the position of (after) the "last match" using [pos](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html). For example

```
$_ = q(abcdef); 

while (/(.)/g)  
{ 
    say "Got $1 at pos ", pos();        

    if (++$cnt == 1) { pos = 4 } 
}
```

which prints

```
Got a at pos 1
Got e at pos 5
Got f at pos 6
```

And you can set it ahead of doing the match as well, as needed

```
$_ = q(abcdef); 

pos = 4; 

while (/(.)/g) { say "Got $1 at pos ", pos() }
```

with

```
Got e at pos 5
Got f at pos 6
```

what answers your direct question. The `\G` does not affect any of this.

But I am not sure whether this is better than what you have since `.` is so simple a "match" that for `.{N}` the regex engine optimizer may index right into `N+1` to search for the following pattern.

---

As it turns out, this is sensitive to the length of the sequence to be skipped (and crucially for very long ones). With it being hundreds of characters the benchmark favors `.{N}`, by up to 25% in my tests.  But from around a `1_000` skipped chars the results reverse rapidly. Ran on v5.16 on a laptop.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $N = 10_000; # 100; 
my $rep = 1;
# Insert  at the beginning a phrase that also matches, for a test
my $str = 'G'.'a'x$rep.'G' . 'b'x($N-2-$rep) . 'G'.'X'x$rep.'G';

sub posit {
    my ($str, $N, $rep) = @_;
    pos ($str) = $N;
    my ($res) = $str =~ /(G.{$rep}G)/g;
    return $res;
}   

sub match {
    my ($str, $N, $rep) = @_;
    my ($res) = $str =~ /.{$N}(G.{$rep}G)/;
    return $res;
}   

say "posit: ", posit($str,$N,$rep), " and match: ", match($str,$N,$rep);
say "Benchmark skipping first $N positions\n";

cmpthese(-10, {
    posit => sub { my $res = posit ($str, $N, $rep) },
    match => sub { my $res = match ($str, $N, $rep) },
});
```

Note that we must have `/g` in the regex for `pos` to have any effect. The result

```
posit: GXG and match: GXG
Benchmark skipping first 10000 positions

          Rate match posit
match 125252/s    --  -70%
posit 414886/s  231%    --
```

Interestingly, using a hard coded `GXG` string considerably changes results in all cases (and always benefits the winner). However, this parameter is likely passed and interpolated so I still use `$rep`. Changing it has no effect, as expected, so I leave it short and simple.

Finally, the question specifies a "*large buffer*."  When I set `$N` above to `100_000` I get

```
Quantifier in {,} bigger than 32766 in regex; marked by ... 100000}(G.{1}G)/ at ...
```

So for really large buffers you *must* use `pos()`.

Note that `pos` also has side effects, influencing further operation.  See docs.

Comment: Nice update! Just one comment: I think you could also use `pos` and `\G`

Comment: @HåkonHægland  I tried, `\G` seems to have no effect.  (When I leave it out it's all good.)  One does need `/g`.  I think for "faking" the "last match" the `\G` won't help. Being unsure I tried all combinations and this appears to be the necessary minimum.  (But I am not sure whether `\G` may affect speed.)  It's tricky :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it, there would be no difference in efficiency. From my understanding of finite automata (which regexes use) every character has to be looped through, anyway. (Otherwise, how would it know when your match starts?) Any regex, (assuming it's been compiled first) will execute in linear time.

If you want to skip a specific number of characters, It might not be a bad idea to take a substring starting at the specified position first, and then apply your regex to that substring.

Comment: Thanks - Extracting a substring surely works, but I should have said that because the buffer is big, I wanted to avoid creating another one. And I was hopping for efficiency because I'm not even asking to look at the skipped chars, so the actual matched position would have been (skipped_chars + found position)

Comment: @philippe_44  The `substr` won't copy the whole string ...?  (Unless you mean that the rest of the original is big, too?)

Comment: Sorry. I was thinking C/C++ where you can simply point at that index of the string and it works like a substring with no copying. There is likely something similar in Perl. But regexes are as far as my knowledge of Perl goes.